# Is there an API to connect to iCloud and get contacts and contact changes?

Tags: objective-c, api, synchronization, icloud

I'm wondering if there is an API of some sort available from Apple for iCloud, to which one can hook into and get notified when contact information changes.

The point of this is that I'm wondering whether it is possible to sync contacts from iCloud outside of iCloud (e.g. from iCloud to some sync server and then to other devices).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here's an implementation of what you are looking for.

Although there is a bug within it, when you have more than 500 contacts, it doesn't work.

I think there is a problem with pagination. If you find out what's wrong with it, do tell.

https://github.com/mindcollapse/iCloud-API

Comment: Hi Itsjustme, do you have example in C#, I try to parse these code to C#, but it returns to me 400 Bad request.

Comment: Worth noting that it's based on non-public API, which means it might be very brittle.